# Cutting Algorithm in Excel VBA to minimise wastage when ordering materials

Tags: algorithm, excel, sorting, vba

I am working on an excel spreadsheet to minimise wastage when ordering cables. I am currently working in excel VBA. The Cable details look like the image below where the Cable ID is the unique ID.

#### Cable Details Screenshot

[image: Cable Details Screenshot]

For each upcoming month I need to produce an Order Form (as per below) to send to the supplier. The attached example has not been optimized and you can see there is a lot of wastage.

#### Example Order Form Screenshot, Cable Drums not optimized

[image: Example Order Form Screenshot, Cable Drums not optimized]

I need to create an algorithm that matches:
Cable Type, Cable Size & Delivery Date and optimizing the cable (circuit) lengths which can fit on each drum (usually 500m length capacity).

For example, i have 5 cables that have the same 3 criteria as mentioned above but they have lengths of 250, 300, 150, 150,100 . If my drum size is 500m length of cable, I dont want 250 on drum 1, 300+150 on drum 2 and 150+100 on drum 3 as that is a total wastage of 550m. If i have 250+150+100 on drum 1 and 300+150 on drum 2 then I have only 50m wastage.

I require a stacking algorithm that searches through the cable details spreadsheet and tests all possible outcomes to minimise ordering wastage.

There are multiple cable types and each cable type has multiple cable sizes.

Ordering is done on a monthly basis. If we have stock left over from a previous month I can factor that in at a later date.

Currently I have code that will loop through the cables and fit additional cables onto each drum, but only in the order it appears in the list. Please see my (messy) code below.

```html
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim OrderDate As String, CableType As String, CableID As String, DrumID As String
Dim Item As Integer, CableLen As Integer, DrumSize As Integer, CableSize As Integer, OrderRow As Integer, DrumTest As Integer

'Store Order Date, Drum Size and beg. of Drum ID String
OrderDate = Cells(3, 16) & " " & Cells(4, 16)
DrumSize = Cells(5, 16)
DrumID = UCase(Left(Cells(3, 16), 3)) & "-" & Right(Cells(4, 16), 2) & "-" & "CD" & "-"
DrumNo = 1
OrderRow = 2
'Count how many cables in the table
NoCables = Application.CountA(Columns(1))

For a = 2 To NoCables
    'Loop through the cables to find a matching date
    If Cells(a, 9) = OrderDate Then
        For c = 2 To OrderRow
            'Check to see if Cable Type & Cable Size already in the order form
            If Cells(a, 4) = Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(c, 3) Then
                If Cells(a, 5) = Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(c, 4) Then
                    GoTo LoopExit
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        'Enter DrumID & first line of details
        CableType = Cells(a, 4)
        CableSize = Cells(a, 5)
        CableLen = Cells(a, 6)
        CableID = Cells(a, 2)
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 1) = DrumID & DrumNo
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 2) = CableID
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 3) = CableType
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 4) = CableSize
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 5) = CableLen
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 8) = CableLen
        DrumCurr = CableLen
        'Search through remaining cables to find cables that match the 3 criteria
        For b = a + 1 To NoCables
            If Cells(b, 9) = OrderDate Then
                If Cells(b, 4) = CableType Then
                    If Cells(b, 5) = CableSize Then
                        CableID = Cells(b, 2)
                        CableLen = Cells(b, 6)
                        DrumTest = DrumCurr + CableLen
                        'Test to see if cummulative cable len is larger than drum size
                        If DrumTest > DrumSize Then
                            'Start a new drum number if previous one exceeded
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 9) = DrumSize - DrumCurr
                            DrumNo = DrumNo + 1
                            OrderRow = OrderRow + 2
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 1) = DrumID & DrumNo
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 2) = CableID
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 3) = CableType
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 4) = CableSize
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 5) = CableLen
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 8) = CableLen
                            DrumCurr = CableLen
                        Else
                            'Add to the current drum
                            OrderRow = OrderRow + 1
                            DrumCurr = DrumTest
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 2) = CableID
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 3) = CableType
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 4) = CableSize
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 5) = CableLen
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 8) = DrumCurr
                            Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow - 1, 8) = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next b
        'Start a new drum and state excess length
        DrumNo = DrumNo + 1
        Worksheets("Order Form").Cells(OrderRow, 9) = DrumSize - DrumCurr
        OrderRow = OrderRow + 2
    End If
LoopExit:
Next a

End Sub
```

I'm sure I can clean the code up using with sheets function. However, to get the optimization that I require, i think i will require to add cables to an array and somehow select ones which combine to equal 500. Perhaps some sort of bubble sort to get the larger lengths to the top of the list? Any comments/ideas are welcome.

Comment: Suggest you search on Google for bin fitting algorithms and start writing your code. If you get stuck you can post another question asking for assistance. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to frame your question. Stack Overflow is not a "please write my code for me" service!

Comment: ***I require a stacking algorithm that searches through the cable details spreadsheet and tests all possible outcomes to minimise ordering wastage.*** Get your wallet out and try a site where you can hire online freelancers ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i have updated my posts. I am only after some tips and/or direction. not the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

If I see that right, your problem can be transformed into the [Activity selection problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem), that means the Greedy algorithm delivers an optimal value.

I don't know about VBA, but this is how it would look in (pseudo) code (it's actually JS.)

You would have object of the form `{ id: 'LV01E', value: 120 }` and send an array of these in the algorithm.

```
function optimize(objArr, maxSize) {
    let ret = [[]]
    let idx = 0

    while (objArr.length) {
        let sizeLeft = size - ret[idx].reduce((sum, obj) => sum + obj.value, 0)  // size of current bucket
        // find the biggest element that fits in sizeLeft
        let big = objArr.reduce((big, obj) => obj.value <= sizeLeft && big.value < obj.value ? obj : big, { value: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY })
        if (big.id) {
            // add the biggest element to the current array
            ret[idx] = [ ...ret[idx], big]
            // and remove it from the output
            objArr = objArr.filter(obj => obj.id !== big.id)
        } else {
            ret.push([])
            ++idx
        }
    }
    return ret
}

let r = optimizer([{ id: 1, value: 250 }, 
                   { id: 2, value: 100 },
                   { id: 3, value: 150 }, 
                   { id: 4, value: 150 }, 
                   { id: 5, value: 300 }], 500)
```

results in

```
[ [ { id: 5, value: 300 }, { id: 3, value: 150 } ],
  [ { id: 1, value: 250 }, { id: 4, value: 150 }, { id: 2, value: 100 } ] ]
```